# Solving Diophantine Equation $8^k={p+q}{p+q+4pq(p-q)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am still currently working out how to solve this diophantine equation 
$8^k={p+q}{p+q+4pq(p-q)}$

This is in connection to solving Fermat's number $F_n$ where n=even.

It turns out that when that particular diophantine equation have non-trivial solution then $F_n$ is composite if $3k+1=2^n$

Comment: added mathjax delimiters, sorry if that wrecks it.

Comment: Do you have a numerical example, please?